# How to reuse existing models in LUIS

Tags: azure, nlp, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Since I cannot modify builtin models (entities, intents..) as provided by the LUIS.ai, How can I import them into my own model in a way that I can modify them further specific to my scenario(s).

Some of the contextual information can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1694#issuecomment-305531910

I am using Azure Bot Service with Node.js

Comment: Please provide a bit more of details of your underlying problem.

Comment: See the provided github link to know more context - I paste the guy's comment over here, he probably works for MS/LUIS

Comment: Stevenic: Normally you can log into LUIS and train it to fix the unrecognized entities. You can't do that with the built in models so there's nothing you can fix. Fortunately it's pretty easy to build a custom model that des the same thing.

Comment: I read that post; still is unclear what do you want to modify; what's your problem, etc. Do you want to modify built-in entities? Why?

Comment: Hopefully I'm wrong, but I don't know of a way to export the prebuilt entities. As Ezequiel said, once you begin using a prebuilt domain, you can add to it just as you would for an entirely custom LUIS app. Which prebuilt entities are you trying to modify?

Comment: For example (builtin) weather entity - is giving only city - while the weather APIs want both the city and the country; and I would not prefer to use the (builtin) geography entity. I guess that with builtin/domain entities behind the scene there are already trained utterances - that's why it could be useful to use them - and if that's true - I want to further add more utterances into them or update existing things in the builtin entity to my liking - same as what I think mr Stevenic of Microsoft said on GitHub.

Comment: Also geography.country entity does not recognize UAE but does so for United Arab Emirates - so how can I make it recognize that..

Comment: Ah this is a known limitation on the geography prebuilt, and enhancements are in the works. For the time being (and if you have the list entity count) use the [Closed List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-entity-types) to account for `"UAE"`. Here's an issue on GH that talks about the [prebuilt geography entity](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2598#issuecomment-294257608).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [new prebuilt domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-use-prebuilt-domains), once you add them to your model, you should be able to tweak them.

If you are using the [Cortana prebuilt app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/cortana-prebuilt-app), I don't think you will be able to update it; however, the documentation contains some information if you want to "mimic" it.

If you explain exactly what are your scenarios, we might be able to come up with other alternatives.

Comment: "If you are using the new prebuilt domains, once you add them to your model, you should be able to tweak them." - This might work for me - I will need to read more on it then.
(I might come back later as working on other projects as well - Thanks)

Comment: Tweaking or Customizing the builtin domains is limited to adding further your own utterances and retrain OR to customize it by removing not-required entities or intents. Not a customization available to modify the builtin entity in order to take advantage of already trained builtin domain. For example converting/tweaking Weather.Location (that caters only City or a Country or just any place) to be able to handle City,Country pair is not possible and you end up creating your own new entity altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a straight-forward way to go about doing this, but you could take the .csv logs from LUIS and incorporate it into your model; at the least the response column data is in json format.

Comment: This is too cumbersome plus seems pretty unsure or imperfect way with lot of manual efforts..
Beside what can u do beside importing an existing app to create a new app from scratch (not import part of stuff into an existing luis app)

Comment: Ezequiel's answer puts forth a good new feature that slipped my mind. What is your LUIS app's culture? Is it in English?

Comment: At the moment, its English.
Yes, Tweaking the builtin entity might work but I need to read and test out more to know further..